# JQuery Detect If in Homepage and Homepage PLUS url Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, pathname

I am using this code to detect the homepage and it works great:

```
var url= window.location.href;
if(url.split("/").length>3){
    alert('You are in the homepage');
}
```

My problem is that I also need to detect if the url has variables for example:

```
mysite.com?variable=something
```

I need to also detect if the url has variables on it too

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [window.location docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) , the information you want is in `location.search` , so a function to check it could just be:

```
function url_has_vars() {
   return location.search != "";
}
```

Answer (score 81):

Using `window.location.pathname` could work too:

```
if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){
    // Index (home) page

} else {
    // Other page
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
}
```

See [MDN info on window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/pathname).

Comment: `if ( window.location.pathname == '/' || window.location.pathname == '/index.php'){ // your stuff }`

Comment: perfect !! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can find out if you're on the homepage by comparing href to origin:

```
window.location.origin == window.location.href
```

To get the query parameters you can use the answer here:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: I noticed that href can return the url with a trailing slash, eg mysite.com/ , while origin is without a slash...

Comment: This answer is wrong: it fails because
`window.location.origin` is `http://www.mywebsite.com`
while
`window.location.href` is `http://www.mywebsite.com/`

Answer (score 3):

if current url is xxxxx.com something like that, then xxx

```
if (window.location.href.split('/').pop() === "") { 
    //this is home page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a query string searching function to do this..

```
function getParameterByName(name) {  
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");  
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),  
        results = regex.exec(location.search);  
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));  
}
```

Before redirect check the query string and match with the expected value and redirect as requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from **Mataniko** suggestion, I slightly modified it to fix its issue:

```
if (window.location.origin + "/" == window.location.href ) {
  // Index (home) page
  ...
}
```

In this way, this test pass only in homepage